# Is there a weapons list/unlock guide for Earth Defense Force 2025?

Tags: earth-defense-force-2025

For EDF 2017, the prequel, I found this: http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/929255-earth-defense-force-2017/faqs/48650, which helpfully lists every weapon in the game, and more importantly, the minimum mission number and difficulty required to unlock the weapon, but I have found no such list for the new game, EDF 2025.

Does one exist?

So far I've done searches on google, checked [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/684232-earth-defense-force-2025), checked to see if there was an [EDF 2025 wikia page](http://theearthdefenseforce.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Defense_Force_2025), and checked the [manual](http://www.d3p.us/Manuals/EDF2025_XBOX_manual_final.pdf), but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Its a work in progress, and some  items may be missing or the translations might be wrong but its the best list i found

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/684232-earth-defense-force-2025/68676470

Comment: I tried to edit this answer, but it says it's awaiting peer review, and it's been a day without peer review, so I'm just writing this here. The googledoc spreadsheet that the forum post contains is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzMFU1jQ797wRzItUFZsLTlBSzQ/edit?usp=sharing) and the Japanese language website that the information originally came from is [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&ie=UTF-8&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fweapon.edf.jpn.com%2F). Apparently some forum posters found some discrepancies between the list and the English version of the game, but it's close.